# Visual Studio macro that navigates to file and function of selected text

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-macros

I work a lot with WPF, and have lots of files in a project which makes navigation sometimes a bugger. I tried to write a macro that helps me at it, but I haven't managed doing so far after struggling a few hours. And not using VB at all, it makes it a bit harder. Maybe someone can push me into the right direction, or help me out to accomplish it.

What I try to achieve is the following macro:

- Retreive the selected text

-> `CType(objDocument.Object, EnvDTE.TextDocument).Selection`

- Check if the word starts with 'Controllername'

-> `text.Startswith("Controllername"))`

- Remove double qoutes

-> `Text.Replace(Chr(34), "").Split("/")`

- Search for the file in the project where the function is located
- Go to the line number of that function

The reason why I want to create this macro is because of the fact that in WPF, I use actionlinks which refer to a "controller/action", which is in stringformat. With this macro I could select the "controller/action" text, hit the keybinding, and go to the function (or display an error for instance if it doesn't exist).

Thanks for the input in advance! :)